# Android maths: Why is sum returning 1.0?

Tags: android, math

Context: I am creating a game that gives a score based on a `decimal` between `0` and `1`.

In the `equation` shown below I am getting the answer `1.0`, which is unexpected as the answer should always be `below` 10.

I don't understand why this is the case?

Sum:

```
double decScore= 1- ((turns-minPossible)/(maxPossible-minPossible));
```

`Sample Data` being entered

```
turns=20;
minPossible=8;
maxPossible=120;
```

The answer I am expecting is `0.89`

Comment: I would guess this is a rounding issue in the subtraction which causes `0` to be subtracted. What are the types of the variables involved?

Comment: -1 question is offtopic :`Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example` ... this code works as expected: http://ideone.com/3rtkcD

Comment: Thank you ideone.com looks useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are subtracting integers therefore the result is 1.0.

You need to cast them to double before so the it's calculated in the precision of a double not an int.

```
double decScore= 1 - (((double)turns-minPossible)/((double)maxPossible-minPossible));
```

Or simply have them declared as double in the first place:

```
double turns=20.0;
double minPossible=8.0;
double maxPossible=120.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the variables turns,min and max are integers then this is an integer division 12/112 = 0

Change them into doubles or type cast them

Answer (score 0):

What are the types of turns, minPossible and maxPossible? If they are int, you are applying integer division and you should cast them

```
(float)(turns-minPossible)/(float)(maxPossible-minPossible));
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you must change turns/minPossible/maxPossible to type double, 
in your example its integer right?